# kernel mod allocate memory

Tags: c++, c, driver, windows-kernel

i developing kervel driver and dell communicating with each other.
try to make a snapshot function and walk function

my struct is

```
struct SM_MSI {
  wchar_t* Name;
  SIZE_T Size;
  uintptr_t Address;
};
```

in my snapshot function i do this.

```
        ModulesList = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(SM_MSI) * index);
        if (ModulesList == NULL) // check memory is allocated or not.
        {
            return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        }
        index = 0;
        for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = (PLIST_ENTRY)((PPEB_LDR_DATA)pPeb->Ldr)->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink;
            pListEntry != &((PPEB_LDR_DATA)pPeb->Ldr)->InLoadOrderModuleList; pListEntry = (PLIST_ENTRY)pListEntry->Flink)
        {
            PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InLoadOrderLinks);
            if (pEntry->BaseDllName.Buffer > 0 && pEntry->BaseDllName.Length < 256) {
                ModulesListCount = ModulesListCount + 1;

                SM_MSI temp = { 0 };
                temp.Name = (wchar_t*)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, sizeof(wchar_t) * 256);
                if (temp.Name != NULL)
                    wcscpy_s(temp.Name, 256, pEntry->BaseDllName.Buffer);

                temp.Size = pEntry->SizeOfImage;
                temp.Address = (uintptr_t)pEntry->DllBase;

                memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)ModulesList + ((index++) * sizeof(SM_MSI))), &temp, sizeof(SM_MSI));
            }
        }
```

in my walk function i do this

```
NTSTATUS ProcModulesWalk(OUT SM_MSI* module_sys_info) {
  if (ModulesListCount == 0)
      return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;

  memcpy(module_sys_info, (SM_MSI*)((ULONG_PTR)ModulesList) + ModulesListIndex++, sizeof(SM_MSI));

  if (ModulesListIndex >= ModulesListCount) {
      ModulesListCount = 0;
      ModulesListIndex = 0;

      ExFreePool(ModulesList); // free memory 
      DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "free memory\n");
  }
  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

when i use this functions in my driver entry(when the driver load) all work good.
but when i call it from the dll all "word fine" only for 2 seconds and then i get blue screen.

when i try to remove the Name variable from the SM_MSI struct all work perfect.!!
so i understand the problem is the "wchar_t* Name" but i need this name
so any idea what to do?

OK GUYS i solved it i forgat to alloc memory before i send it to the dll and then to driver.

Comment: Is it failing on the allocate or the wscpy?

Comment: you're memcpy-ing into module_sys_info from ModulesList and after that ModulesList may/is deallocated. Is module_sys_info.Name (ptr) still valid ?

Comment: @stark i dont know becuse i get the blue screen after i recive all the data from the driver.

Comment: What is the purpose of this driver? What is it supposed to accomplish? This sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: @engf-010 yes. all the data come from the driver into dll and the to the app and after 1-2 seconds i get blue screen

Comment: my best guess is : replace your shallow-copy (memcpy) with a deep-copy ,allocate a buffer for module_sys_info.Name and use wscpy to fill it from ModuleList.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to request your driver to find the base address and size of a module in a process given the module name. The solution is to not use a driver at all, and simply call EnumProcessModules. If the process you are trying to access has special protection, you shouldn't be tampering with it anyways; that would result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: not saying you're wrong ,but you're making an awfull lot of assumptions that are not reflected in the OP's question. Or do you have some inside info that we don't have ?

Comment: @engf-010 What kind of assumptions would those be?

Comment: your first sentence ! This may very well be true but then again it may just looks like that. Adding 'If' or 'It looks like' in front of it makes your answer a bit less ESP.

Comment: @engf-010 ESP? Pun intended?